# Calculating Days With Equivalent String Value Using Datediff Computed Column Specification Formula

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datediff, calculated-columns, date-difference

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I made a computed column on my table which is ResidencyStatus. Using datediff in ResidencyStatus I want to know the difference between the current date (now date) and my other date column ResidencyDate.

- Now, if the result is less than or equal to 183 days(less than or equal to 6 months) then I want to put the string 'Transient' in ResidencyStatus.
- If the result is greater than or equal to 184 days(greater than or equal to 6 months and 1 day) AND less than or equal to 1825 days(less than or equal to 4 years and 364 days) then the value will be 'Migrant'.
- If the result is greater than or equal to 1826 days(greater than or equal to 5 years) then the value will be 'Resident'.

I tried using this formula in the computed column:

```
(case when (datediff(day,[ResidencyDate],getdate()))<=183 then 'Transient' elseif (datediff(day,[ResidencyDate],getdate())>=184 and <=1825 then 'Migrant' elseif (datediff(day,[ResidencyDate],getdate())>=1826 then 'Resident' end
```

...but this error occurs "Error validating the formula for column ResidencyStatus." Can you give me an idea on how to make this formula work or maybe an alternative solution?

Comment: Instead of elseif use WHEN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `elseif` in a `case` statement.  The `case` statement takes a series of `when` clauses, and these are evaluated in order.  So, you can express what you want as:

```
(case when datediff(day, [ResidencyDate], getdate()) <= 183 then 'Transient'
      when datediff(day, [ResidencyDate], getdate()) <= 1825 then 'Migrant' 
      else 'Resident'
 end)
```

Okay, this does have a slight difference from your logic.  The `else` will include `NULL` values.  This is easy enough to fix:

```
(case when datediff(day, [ResidencyDate], getdate()) <= 183 then 'Transient'
      when datediff(day, [ResidencyDate], getdate()) <= 1825 then 'Migrant' 
      when datediff(day, [ResidencyDate], getdate()) > 1825 then 'Resident' 
 end)
```

This will return `NULL` in those cases.

Comment: I think for `Migrant` you were missing to check `... >=184`

Comment: @NoDisplayName . . . That check is unnecessary.  The first `where` clause handles that case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
  select 
  ....
  CASE
     WHEN ( Datediff(day, [ResidencyDate], Getdate()) ) <= 183 THEN 'Transient'
     WHEN Datediff(day, [ResidencyDate], Getdate()) >= 184
          AND Datediff(day, [ResidencyDate], Getdate()) <= 1825 THEN 'Migrant'
     ELSE 'Resident'
   END
  .....
  .....
```

OR use `Between`

```
  select 
  ....
  CASE
     WHEN ( Datediff(day, [ResidencyDate], Getdate()) ) <= 183 THEN 'Transient'
     WHEN Datediff(day, [ResidencyDate], Getdate()) Between 184 and 1825 THEN 'Migrant'
     ELSE 'Resident'
   END
  .....
  .....
```